# Web Page gets cut off

Tags: html

I know a lot of people ask questions on this, but I have a spacing problem with my divs.
My main div tag of my web page is 1024px. The problem is that on smaller screens part of my 
page gets cut off and you have to scroll horizontally. How do I fix that so that the page will
fit in any window? (especially the smaller ones)
I do not want to use the width:100% property cause I already defined the width as 1024px.
Here is my main div tag's properties:

```
<div id="main" style=" margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 50px; width:1024px;">
my content.....
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is you defined the width as 1024 pixels, which is an absolute value.  On screens where the resolution is 1024 pixels, of course it won't all fit on the screen; you have window borders, scroll bars, etc.

Comment: if you declare it to be 1024, then you will get 1024, if you declare it to be 100% then it will fill the window...  if you want to make it fit on smaller without 100% - then try 640...

Comment: You should talk to Doctor Who about the whole "bigger on the inside" technology if you're so adamant about it having a fixed width.

Comment: thank you...You see the problem is that the content in the div has images etc that are 1024px. When I set the width:100%, it pushes the div and its contents to the left of the screen(on a bigger screen >1024px) and if I say width:1024px, it centers my div tag which I prefer...O basically you're saying I should make my main div less than 1024px? and how to I center the div if the content inside is lets say 1000px, and I do not specify the div width?

Answer (score 0):

A more common width for a Web page is 960px just to avoid the problem you are encountering.  Sorry, the only way to fit your page into those smaller screens is to reduce the width for your main div.

Comment: If you are aren't familiar with fluid layouts vs. fixed layouts and their issues, check out this post http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a fixed width, in this case 1024px, you cannot make the page fit in any window.

You should have a read of [Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) which explains how to incorporate  flexibility into your design.

Comment: You're welcome. A Book Apart published Ethan's book on this a few months ago: http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design Well worth $9 (ebook) IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't want it *wider* than 1024px? If so, set the `max-width` property on it:

```
#main { 
    max-width: 1024px; 
}
```

then, it will fit the screen, but not go larger than 1024.

Comment: thank you, but that doesn't fix my problem, the page still gets cut of on smaller screens with the width set to max-width:1024px